# Extracting videos for VideoView for Android Application.

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

So I am trying to setup an Activity in which the user can Browse for a video from his respective storage and then play it in using VideoView. How can I do that? I have written some code below.

Also I am using a Nexus 7 so it does not have an SD CARD in it. How to make a generalized code to take videos from Internal/External Memory?

```
public class VideoCapture extends Activity {

  private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.gc();
        String filename = "/sdcard/Video/sample.mp4";
        //String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample;
        VideoView videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        setContentView(videoView1);
        videoView1.setVideoPath(filename);
        videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView1.requestFocus();
        videoView1.start();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0,"FullScreen");

      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
      case INSERT_ID:
          createNote();
      }
      return true;
  }

  private void createNote() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `ListView` for your Activity for that ListView also create adapter class 
then add following code into Activity

```
private List <String> getSD()
{
    List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
    File f = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Vidoes");
        // to get Internal Storage use File m_applicationDir = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "");
        //File f = new File(m_applicationDir + "/Vidoes");
    File[] files = f.listFiles ();

    for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
    {
        File  file = files[i];
        Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
        it.add (file.getPath());
    }
    return it;
}
```

set this list to your list Adapter. And Play your Videos on click of listitem

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I got it. I just had to setVideoURI to the video that I selected from gallery and play it. Let me know if anyone needs help setting it up.